# JSON parsing syntax error with manually entered string

Tags: javascript, python

When I try to stringyfy

```
ABC
<a href="abc.co.dds">
 dfsdsf
</a>
```

JSON gives me

```
"ABC\n<a href=\"abc.co.dds\">\n dfsdsf\n</a>"
```

but when I try

```
s=('"ABC\n<a href=\"abc.co.dds\">\n dfsdsf\n</a>"');
JSON.parse(s)
```

I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` on my console

How can I parse a manually entered string with JSON?

Comment: I'm confused as to why this is tagged as Python - the code doesn't look like Python (why the semicolon? And the Python JSON module is `json`).

Answer (score 1):

From the [JSON specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627) (second 2):

> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.

Since you are starting with a string (and not an object or an array), a JSON serializer should (IMO) throw an exception instead of giving you an escaped string.

You can work around your problem by wrapping your string in `{ "data": your_string }` before converting to JSON (using whatever syntax that language you are using supports for objects/hash maps/associative arrays/etc). Obviously, you'll need to access `foo.data` after parsing the JSON to a native object at the other end).